# Running App as root using Apple Script?

Tags: macos, sudo, root, terminal.app, applescript

I am trying to use an Apple Script to run an application as root without asking for password all the time. I used this Apple Script code:

```
do shell script "/Applications/MyApp.app" user name "<username>" password "<password>" with administrator privileges
```

This works, but it makes the Apple Script to keep on running without closing. Not only that, the application that runs using this Apple Script gets stuck and could not be closed unless macOS is restarted. Even Force Quit is not working.

I also tried this method,

I created another script that can allow the app to run as root without asking for password. Here is that code,

```
set sudoersFilePath to "/etc/sudoers"
set newEntry to "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Applications/MyApp.app"

do shell script "echo " & quoted form of newEntry & " | sudo tee -a " & sudoersFilePath with administrator privileges
```

The above script adds a line in the `sudoers` file. You can access this file from Terminal using this command,

```
sudo visudo
```

This will list all the files in the list that do not require password all the time. In the `sudoers` file, it has added the line to give full root access to the macOS user. This file contains the required application, but it is not running as root.

So, how to run the application as root without asking for password using Apple Script or any other method?